# Is it possible to get 3 elements in a string/list/array, the first two being consecutive and the third separated from them by a step?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, numpy-slicing

Given the array:

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.array(range(10))
print(arr)
[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

is it possible to get in one single slice ex. arr[1:6:1] the numbers [1, 2, 5]?

I've tried everything, from steps to multiple slicing, it seems I cannot get past the uneven step between the numbers. I'm pretty sure it's not possible, but if it is, I'd like to hear it since I wasted a few hours on this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In numpy, you can directly pass a list of indeces instead of a slice object:

```
arr[[1, 2, 5]]
```

If there is an underlying pattern to those indeces you can use it to create the index list.